# Translate the text under MIT to CC BY-SA project

Tags: mit, creative-commons, cc-by-sa

There is one "document only" opensource project under MIT license.
So it is only text files under Markdown syntax with useful info for people.

It is in language A (human language, not programming)
I want to make similar one, but for my native language (Ukrainian).

I think that Creative Commons share-alike (cc by-sa 4.0) is more suitable for such kind of projects, but worry could I then use some translated part of that another project?

Because in "common case" (not for MIT or any other opensource licenses) translation is authored by translator ( but author should permit translation)

Answer (score 1):

The MIT license doesn't limit any such use, so that should be (legally) fine.

On the other hand, the authors did choose the license for a reason, common courtesy would dictate to keep any derivatives (like a translation certainly is) under the same license. At very least, contact the original authors and ask. They'll probably also want to keep track of translations and other derivatives.